# Why does this recursive method function this way?

Tags: methods, recursion

The program displays the result of "5," but I don't see how it gets to that answer because of the "+1" that proceeds the "result mystery(n/20) + 1"

Can anyone take me through the logical steps the computer takes to get this?

```
    public class Experimental{

    public static int mystery(int n){   
        if (n <= 0) { return 0; }   
        return mystery(n / 2) + 1;
        }//ends method

public static void main(String[] args){
    System.out.println(mystery(20));
}//ends method
}//ends class
```

Comment: So far I'm only seeing this as the (n/2) part. It keeps cutting itself in half until eventually it hits 0, but when does that "+1" come into play?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a recursive call. It ends when n equals zero (it can never become negative). It takes 5 divisions by 2 to reach zero. The best thing for you to do is to take a piece of paper and to see how this unfolds.

```
mystery(20/2) + 1 =
(mystery(20/2/2) + 1) + 1 =
((mystery(20/2/2/2) + 1) + 1) + 1 = 
(((mystery(20/2/2/2/2) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1 = 
((((mystery(20/2/2/2/2/2) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1) + 1 =
0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 1 = 5
```

Hope this helps. Computers are much better in recursion than humans...

Comment: Perfect. Soon as I unlock the ability, you're getting an upvote.

Answer (score 0):

Yes!  In fact, a debugger such as `gdb` can you take you through the logical steps the computer takes.

1. Compile the program with `-g` flag.
2. Run `gdb a.out` (or your program name).
3. Google `gdb cheatsheet` for info on how to set a breakpoint and step through your code.

Comment: Total newbie here, how do I compile a program with a "-g flag"? What is that anyway? And how do I go about doing step 2?